# Mongoose sorting by createdAt

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a getPosts controller on my Post Controller, my goal is to sort it by the createdAt time to maintain order because when I map it on the frontend it starts from the last created to the latest.

```
const getPosts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find().sort([createdAt, 1]);
  res.json(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

sort() can't take arrays it either takes string or an object

`const posts = await Post.find().sort({createdAt: 1});`

also you can use **" asc "**,**" ascending "** instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mongo query `sort()` to get that. It can take value 1 or -1 according to sorting order, you can read mongo db document for more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).

Also you can put this sort query in timestamp of these for getting this too.

```
//Sorting by descending order
const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 })

//Sorting by ascending order
const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: 1 })
```

So you can do this:

```
const getPosts = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const posts = await Post.find().sort({ createdAt: 1 })
  res.json(posts)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

sort() takes in either an Object or a String.

the correct syntax should be

```
 const posts = await Post.find().sort({createdAt: 1});
```